# How to model bind XML POST with multiple child nodes in WebAPI (.net core 3)

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a new WebAPI in .NET core 3 which needs to consume XML data POSTed to it. I am able to modelbind an XML document with a single child element, however I cannot modelbind multiple instances of the same child element (equivalent to JSON modelbinding with List or IEnumerable)

The application is running .NET Core 3 version 3.0.100. I have tried to use List and IEnumerable without result. On the XML document I have tried some variations including sending multiple XML documents in the same post request.

My Controller:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class RenewalNoticeJobController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Consumes("application/xml")]
        [Produces("application/xml")]
        [HttpPost("Test")]
        public IActionResult Test([FromBody] IEnumerable<TestDTO> model)
        {
            return Ok(model);
        }
    }
```

My DTO/Model:

```
public class TestDTO
    {
        public string TestValue {get;set;}
    }
```

My XML data sent via POSTman

```
<TestDTO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <TestValue>TestValue 1</TestValue>
    <TestValue>TestValue 2</TestValue>
</TestDTO>
```

The error message I am receiving when using IEnumerable:

```
<problem xmlns="urn:ietf:rfc:7807">
    <status>415</status>
    <title>Unsupported Media Type</title>
    <type>https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13</type>
    <traceId>|1a4dfac4-4f43b1e42224c38a.</traceId>
</problem>
```

And when using List:

```
<problem xmlns="urn:ietf:rfc:7807">
    <status>400</status>
    <title>One or more validation errors occurred.</title>
    <type>https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1</type>
    <traceId>|d6416e-497079dbab2aeefc.</traceId>
    <MVC-Errors>
        <MVC-Empty>An error occurred while deserializing input data.</MVC-Empty>
    </MVC-Errors>
</problem>
```

**Update:**
I have updated the question to be more clear. What I am trying to modelbind one or more instances of the TestDTO model (equivalent to IEnumerable or List.

Comment: The array should be inside TestDTO : public string[] TestValue {get;set;}

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues, one is you need to add xml formatter and another is your xml and model are not sync.

Try follow steps below:

1. `Startup.cs`

   ```
   services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
   ```
2. Model

   ```
   public class TestDTO
   {
           public string[] TestValue { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Action

   ```
   [Consumes("application/xml")]
   [Produces("application/xml")]
   [HttpPost("Test")]
   public IActionResult Test([FromBody] TestDTO model)
   {
       return Ok(model);
   }
   ```
4. Request

   ```
   <TestDTO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
           <TestValue>
                   <string>T1</string>
                   <string>T</string>
           </TestValue>
   </TestDTO>
   ```